# Mustang Library: Converting invalid PDFA3 to valid PDFA3 for building Factur-x

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a facturX using Mustang Library in a webservice. This web service accept a xml string and a base64 PDF.

My issue is that i have no "knowledge" about PDF format that is sent to me. In my service layer class, I build my facturx using ZUGFeRDExporterFromA1.

```
@Override
public FacturxDto createFacturX(FacturxDto facturxDto) {
    context.setContext(facturxDto);
    if (facturxDto.getVersion() == null) {
        facturxDto.setVersion(2);
    }
    if(facturxDto.getPdfDocument() == null) {
        throw new AppServiceException("Pdf is required in the payload");
    }
    if(facturxDto.getXml() == null) {
        throw new AppServiceException("Xml is required in the payload");
    }
    if ((facturxDto.getVersion() < 1) || (facturxDto.getVersion() > 2)) {
        throw new AppServiceException("invalid version");
    }
    try {
        Utils.facturxValidator(facturxDto);
    } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
        throw new AppServiceException(e.getMessage());
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    log.debug("Converting to PDF/A-3u");

    PDFAConformanceLevel pdfaConformanceLevel = Utils.setPdfaConformanceLevel(facturxDto);
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(facturxDto.getPdfDocument().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    byte[] xmlData = facturxDto.getXml().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] pdfData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(facturxDto.getPdfDocument().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    try {
        ZUGFeRDExporterFromA1 ze = new ZUGFeRDExporterFromA1()
                .setProducer("Mustang LIB")
                .setCreator("ME")
                .setProfile(facturxDto.getFxLevel())
                .setZUGFeRDVersion(facturxDto.getVersion())
                .setConformanceLevel(pdfaConformanceLevel)
                .ignorePDFAErrors()
                .load(pdfData);

        ze.attachFile("factur-x.xml", xmlData, "text/xml", "Data");
        
        ze.setXML(xmlData);
        log.debug("Attaching ZUGFeRD-Data");
        ze.disableAutoClose(true);
        ze.export(output);
        byte[] bytes = output.toByteArray();
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        byte[] pdfBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pdfBytes);
        // persist data in db and generate id
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
        FacturxEntity facturxEntity = modelMapper.map(facturxDto, FacturxEntity.class);
        facturxEntity.setStatus(RequestOperationStatus.SUCCESS.name());
        facturxEntity.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        facturxEntity.setFacturxId(Utils.generateId());

        FacturxEntity storedFacturx = facturxRepository.save(facturxEntity);
        FacturxDto returnValue = modelMapper.map(storedFacturx, FacturxDto.class);
        returnValue.setPdfDocument(encoded);
        return returnValue;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new AppServiceException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My issue is here :

```
ZUGFeRDExporterFromA1 ze = new ZUGFeRDExporterFromA1()
        .setProducer("Mustang LIB")
        .setCreator("ME")
        .setProfile(facturxDto.getFxLevel())
        .setZUGFeRDVersion(facturxDto.getVersion())
        .setConformanceLevel(pdfaConformanceLevel)
        .ignorePDFAErrors()
        .load(pdfData);
```

If i don't use ignorePDFAErrors() I do have an exception thrown.
If i use it, my pdf is not PDFA compliant. And it's an issue.

Is there a way to convert on the fly an invalid PDFA to a valid one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. use Mustang's REST API, Mustang Server https://www.mustangproject.org/server/ to correct and export any input PDF file as PDF/A, which also includes files which are already PDF/A-1.

kind regards
Jochen